# how to add and remove the selected checkbox id to and from arraylist in android?

Tags: android

I am storing the selected checkbox value into arraylist when it is selected by the user and removing from the same arraylist when unchecked by the user. But I am having one problem with this. i.e for example I selected the checkboxes 0,1,4,6. Then I unchecked 0th checkbox. But from the arraylist 6 is removed. Next time I unchecked 1th position checkbox. But this time in from the arraylist nothing is deleted. Finally I unchecked 0 and 4 but still nothing is deleted from arraylist. The values 0,1,4 are still existing in the arraylist. How to overcome this issue?
    I want to store the selected items and remove the unselected items. Please help me regarding this....

My Code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> selchkboxlist = new ArrayList<String>();;
String chk;  
cbs = new CheckBox[20]; 
 for(k=0; k<List.size(); k++)
 { 
     arr = List.get(k);
     cbs[k] = new CheckBox(getContext());
     Rl.addView(cbs[k]);
     cbs[k].setText((CharSequence) arr.get(2));
     cbs[k].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));  
     cbs[k].setId(k);

     cbs[k].setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
     { 
         public void onClick(View v) 
         { 
            CheckBox cbs = (CheckBox) v ;
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            chk = Integer.toString(v.getId());
              selchkboxlist.add(chk);
            Toast.makeText(Myclass.this, "Selected CheckBox ID" + v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("selected checkboxes"+selchkboxlist);
            }
            else 
            {
                selchkboxlist.remove(chk);
                  Toast.makeText(Myclass.this, "Not selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  System.out.println("un selected checkboxes"+selchkboxlist);
            }
            }
            });
    }
```

Will be thankful....

Comment: try making your ArrayList static.

Answer (score 0):

In line 4... i guess you should have list size for selchkboxlist .

Comment: Can you give a little more explanation for your answer?  It might help the OP understand a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

create a class like this

```
   public class checkboxList
 {


    private boolean Checked;

    public checkboxList( boolean Checked) {
        super();


        this.Checked = Checked;

    }
public void setChecked(boolean state)
    {
        this.Checked = state;
    }
public boolean getChecked()
 {
 return Checked; 
}
}
```

Then in onclick method  you

```
   if (checkBox.isChecked() == true) {
    checkboxList.get(position).setChecked(true);
                        }
 else {
    checkboxList.get(position).setChecked(false);
                        }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response..when i am giving checkboxList.get(position).setChecked(true); it is asking to create get method in checkboxList class

Comment: i have added the class also checkboxlist class check it

Comment: hi i added                                                       public int getchkposition() { return position;}
public void setchkposition(int position) {  this.position = position;} in checkboxlist class...but still it is asking to create get method

Comment: public boolean getChecked()
    {
        return Checked;
    } add this in the class

Comment: Hi I have created the get method..but still it is saying "Create method 'get(int)' in type checkboxList"

Comment: hi please help me regarding this..finally i want to store the selected and unselected checkboxes into arraylist and have to send those to other page

Comment: use this if (checkBox.isChecked() == true) {
    checkboxList.get(k).setChecked(true);
                        }
 else {
    checkboxList.get(k).setChecked(false);
                        }